# Starting buffer with emacs that behaves like scratch

Tags: emacs, buffer

My preference when creating a document is to open a blank buffer, start typing a few things, then decide what to call the file and save it.  This is what I'd do with notepad.  But with emacs it forces you to decide what to call the buffer before you can start typing.

Right now when I launch emacs I get the scratch buffer.  If I edit and try to save scratch (ctrl-x ctrl-s) it allows me to enter where I want to save it in the default directory.  I guess the scratch is some kind of virtual buffer with no filename.

If I change the starting buffer from scratch to something else, then attempting to save that buffer just saves to whatever I defined the file as.

I want an empty starting buffer that, when I attempt to save, lets me define the the filename, i.e. it behaves like the scratch buffer when saving, but is empty.

*EDIT also when trying to specify 'initial buffer choice' it overrides my choice when launching a document from its icon, how to avoid this?

Comment: What are the properties of your icon (which I guess is a shortcut that opens Emacs)? If the icon says to open a particular file or directory then yes, that will override what `initial-buffer-choice` says. What happens is that both are done, and the file specified by the shortcut is done second, so it shows. E.g., I use this in a shortcut: `D:\Emacs-24-2013-10-19\bin\runemacs.exe --debug-init "d:\my\path\to\my\dir"`, so Emacs opens to that directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments you can use the empty scratch buffer. If you do not like it use, e.g.,

```
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(switch-to-buffer "**")
```

as the last thing in your .emacs file. After the first answer about <kbd>C-x b</kbd> you could determine such stuff for yourself with the help of emacs for this keystrokes. You get this help via <kbd>C-h k</kbd> followed by the keysequence of interest.

I have just added `(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)` so that you can see the `**`-buffer  immediately after startup.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way: <kbd>C-x b</kbd>. Enter a random name, like `temp`.
You get a buffer in fundamental-mode that isn't bound to any file.
Then you can save it as you wish.

Comment: I want this all automated so that when I launch emacs I'm at an unbound buffer.  What would I put into my .emacs file for this?  thx

Comment: One possibility: Set `(setq initial-scratch-message "")` and use the scratch buffer. (But maybe the `lisp-interaction-mode` is disturbing?) If you need afterwards a new buffer in the same emacs you could do `C-x b` as the original answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Customize option `initial-buffer-choice`.  Set it to the name of a buffer of your choice, instead of the default value of `nil` or `t` for buffer `*scratch*`.

```
,----
| initial-buffer-choice is a variable defined in `startup.el'.
| Its value is nil
| 
| Documentation:
| Buffer to show after starting Emacs.
| If the value is nil and `inhibit-startup-screen' is nil, show the
| startup screen.  If the value is a string, switch to a buffer
| visiting the file or directory specified by that string.  If the
| value is a function, switch to the buffer returned by that
| function.  If t, open the `*scratch*' buffer.
| 
| A string value also causes emacsclient to open the specified file
| or directory when no target file is specified.
| 
| You can customize this variable.
| 
| This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
| version 24.4 of Emacs.
`----
```

(That doc string is from a recent Emacs development snapshot.  The Emacs 24.3. doc string is slightly different.)

Comment: My doc says that `initial-buffer-choice` runs `find-file` which is not exactly what the OP wants... But, maybe one could use the "function" feature.

Comment: @user2708138: Your doc is apparently the Emacs 24.3 doc (or earlier). I mentioned that it is different. So yes, to benefit from this change before Emacs 24.4 is released (which should be soon), you need a development snapshot.

Comment: Hm, would it also open a buffer not visiting a file? I would not expect that from the above recitation of the new documentation. The only way would be the "function"-feature, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user2708138: Yes, it will.  And BTW, the `find-file` behavior of Emacs 24.3 acts the same, if the file does not yet exist.  `find-file` does not require the file to exist.  If the option value is a string then it is given as a file name to `find-file` -- in Emacs 24.4 as in 24.3.

Comment: I assume a problem is that the buffer is associated to the file with the given name. If you press `C-x C-s` the file is saved with this name. If one uses `switch-to-buffer` then `buffer-file-name` is `nil` and emacs always asks where to save the buffer.

Comment: @user2708138: What you describe is the behavior.  Whether that is *a problem* or not is in the eye of the beholder. It all depends on just what behavior one wants.  (`C-x C-w` always asks where to save...) There are lots of possibilities, each with their own characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is answered, but I thought someone else (and possibly the original poster) would appreciate this.

```
(defun my/new-scratch ()
    ; Returns the existing *scratch* buffer or creates a new one
    (interactive)
    (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*scratch*")))
```

Now you can bind this to something you like and you can make a new scratch as often as you like but not need to start a new emacs every time.

```
;; replaces set-goal-column on C-x C-n
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-n") 'my/new-scratch)
```